# AWS EC2 loses connection after a while - Operation timed out

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, timeout

This question has been asked a lot, but I just can't get it to work, so here it goes again.

I have an ubuntu machine configured in AWS. I've reviewed the configuration countless times.

After booting my machine, I can connect trough ssh for a while. Then, without any apparent reason, I lose the connection and cannot connect anymore. Any attempt results in Operation time out.

I've tried to launch different machines, both with the same result. The only way I can connect trough SSH is after a reboot. After a minute or two, I lose the connection again.

After some trial and error, it's not only the ssh connection that its lost. HTTP or ICMP becomes unavailable to.

The machines has an elastic IP public IP address.

Any ideas on the root case for this?

EDIT: I also tried this: sudo ufw allow 22. No effect. Anyone?

Comment: Is it a low RAM instance? My guess would be the ssh process getting OOM killed. Check the logs.

Comment: What is the instance type, what AMI are you running, and what software is installed? I'd like to see a screenshot of "top" as close to "failure" as you can. I'd also install something like monit to see if it keeps running and shows the problem, though I'm not sure it will.

Comment: Hi, 
I've tried a t2.micro both with ubuntu 16.04 and Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.1. Also I've tried a t2.nano with ubuntu 16.04. All configuration got the same problem. 
I did install any kind of software on the first try. After some mor tried I've installed docker a put a container to run with a web service. The web service become unavailable ate the same time the ssh became unavailable. 

Thanks

Comment: This was a problem with AWS itself. If you have the same problem, is better to contact technical support at AWS.